# Сортировка подсчетом и сортировка по байтам на ее основе

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Реализую сортировку подсчетом. Возникла проблема в том, что моя реализация не обрабатываем один элемент массива - наибольший. Вместо него в результате выводится мусор. Вот код:

```
void CountingSort(int a[], int b[], int len, int k){
    int *c = new int[k + 1];    //Временное рабочее хранилище c[0..k]

    for(int i = 0; i < (k + 1); i++)
        c[i] = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        c[a[j]]++;
    //В c[i] хранится кол-во элементов, равных i
    for(int i = 1; i < (k + 1); i++)
        c[i] = c[i] + c[i - 1];
    //В c[i] хранится кол-во элементов, не превосходящих i
    for(int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        b[c[a[j]]] = a[j];
        c[a[j]]--;
    }
    delete[] c;
}
```

Я понимаю этот алгоритм так. На вход подаются числа большие или равные нулю, но не превосходящие число k. Это значит, что можно создать вспомогательный массив c[0..k], в котором можно хранить количество каждого из чисел последовательности. Это возможно, потому что все числа от 0 до k, и их можно использовать в качестве индексов.

Во втором цикле считаем количество каждого из чисел.

В третьем вычисляем количество чисел, не превосходящих i. Т.к. все индексы массива c идут по порядку и каждый соответствует одному из чисел в последовательности, то понятно, что для вычисления количества чисел, не превосходящих i (знак >=), надо к к количеству числа i прибавить количество числа i - 1. Начиная со второго элемента, постепенно мы обработаем таким образом все ячейки.

А вот последний цикл мне совсем непонятен. Какую логику реализует этот код? Каким образом все это работает?

Вызывающая функция:

```
int main(void){
    int v[10] = {9, 0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 5, 6};
    int u[11];

    CountingSort(v, u, 10, 9);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << u[i] << ' ';

    std::cin >> v[0];   //pause
    return 0;
}
```

Также на основе этого алгоритма надо решить такую задачу: "Модифицировать процедуру сортировки подсчетом для сортировки по отдельному (младшему, второму с конца и т.д.) байту числа."

Как выделить байты - понятно. Берем маску 1111 1111b и, сдвигая ее, вырезаем необходимые биты. А как приспособить сортировку подсчетом к такой задаче, я совсем не понимаю. Что подавать на вход алгоритму? Как сортировать по байтам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнём с предпоследнего цикла. После него в `c[i]` находится число, на единицу большее, чем последний индекс, по которому должно лежать число `i`. Понятно, почему? Поскольку элементов, равных 0, ровно `c[0]` штук, первый из них имеет индекс 0, а последний — `c[0] - 1`. Затем, за нулями должны лежать единицы, они начинаются с последнего индекса, на котором закончились нули, а заканчиваются на `c[1] - 1`. И так далее.

Итак, логика последнего цикла такая. Проходим по всему исходному массиву. `j` — текущий индекс. `a[j]` — значение. `c[a[j]]` — индекс сразу вслед за последним индексом для `a[j]`. Правильно было бы сначала уменьшить `c[a[j]]`, получив при этом последний индекс для значения `a[j]` в отсортированном массиве, а затем записывать значение по этому индексу в итоговый массив:

```
c[a[j]]--;
b[c[a[j]]] = a[j];
```

Но алгоритм по ошибке сначала записывает элемент по неправильному индексу, а лишь затем уменьшает его.

Алгоритм, судя по всему, был бы правильным, если бы подсчёт индексов вёлся, как в Паскале, от 1, а не от 0.

---

Я бы, кстати, не пожалел памяти и длинных имён для переменных, читаемость кода важна:

```
void CountingSort(int from[], int to[], int len, int maxval) {
    int *count = new int[maxval + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < (maxval + 1); i++)
        count[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        count[from[j]]++;

    int *topidx = new int[maxval + 1];
    topidx[0] = count[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < (maxval + 1); i++)
        topidx[i] = count[i] + topidx[i - 1];
    delete[] count;

    for (int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        int value = from[j];
        topidx[value]--;
        to[topidx[value]] = value;
    }
    delete[] topidx;
}
```

Рабочий код: http://ideone.com/BeDDUP.

---

А вот более простой алгоритм, который пробегается по всем возможным *значениям* и расставляет их по местам: http://ideone.com/WQ0Rj6. Оба правильные.

---

Для сортировки по отдельному байту при подсчёте количества вместо самого значения надо брать лишь нужный байт этого значения. Симметрично, при поиске индекса для значения поиск в таблице индексов нужно вести не по *всему* значению, а по его нужному байту. Больше не подсказываю в дидактических целях. (Кстати, более простой алгоритм на случай поиска по отдельному байту, видимо, не обобщается так просто.)

Comment: "Понятно, почему?" Кажется, непонятно. Дело в том, что я этот код редактировал, и вместо верхней границы k поставил k+1, потому что пытался решить проблему с неверным результатом, а до этого фиксил выходы за пределы массива. Зря я, наверное, выложил сюда вариант программы со всеми этими k+1. Удивило, что надо "сначала уменьшить". Потому что у Кормена написано именно так.

Comment: @typemoon: Ну, смотрите. Если мы по всему массиву (`2 0 2 0 0`) насчитали 3 нуля, 0 единиц и 2 двойки, то в выходном массиве должно быть _сначала_ три нуля (а значит, их индексы от `0` до `2 = 3 - 1`), ноль единиц и 2 двойки (а значит, их индексы от первого индекса после нулей (это `3`) 2 штуки — это `3 + 0` и `3 + 1`, это на 1 меньше чем 3 + к-во двоек). И так далее.

Comment: @typemoon: Обновил ответ, добавил часть о сортировке по отдельному байту.

Comment: Спасибо, дальше я сам.

Comment: @typemoon: Пожалуйста!